# How to fix negative margin in material ui components, explicit with text content

Tags: javascript, material-ui

I have a problem with the paragraphs in the material-ui components..

I have a problem with the paragraphs in the material-ui components. The specific problem is that when the text exceeds the dimensions of the component it is not kept within it as shown in the figure.

```
<Grid container wrap="nowrap"  css={[borde,{
                              maxWidth: 400
                        }]} >
            <Grid item xs css={beneficiosTab}  >
                <Typography 
 >asdadsdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdadasdsadasdasdasdsadasdasdsads
                </Typography>
            </Grid>
</Grid>
```

I hope that what is shown on the screen is a paragraph within the dimensions of your container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `style={{wordWrap: 'break-word'}}`, i hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```
<Grid container wrap="nowrap"  css={[borde,{
                              maxWidth: 400
                        }]} >
            <Grid item xs css={beneficiosTab}  >
                <Typography style={{wordWrap: 'break-word'}}
 >asdadsdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdadasdsadasdasdasdsadasdasdsads
                </Typography>
            </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanx, its ok now

Comment: If this answer help you out, please mark as correct. Thanks